# Google API map not showing in other site pages but shows on home page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps API on my footer. But when I view in other sub pages the maps do not show. **It shows fine on the home page** but if I go to a url. But if I have it on other pages.

> **Question** how can I make google key restriction work for other pages

[image]

Not Working URL

```
http://dev.example.co.nz/history/gallery
```

Working URL

```
http://dev.example.co.nz/
```

The map gets error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a wildcard at the end for the referer to be validated on all pages of your site.  Add this via the Google API Manager as a valid referer:

```
http://dev.example.co.nz/*
```

Comment: Because I am using vhost on my localhost is there any difference